# Double wide element in a grid layout—how to maintain aspect ratio of child element?

Tags: css, css-grid, aspect-ratio

I have a grid of four equal columns. Each column contains a child element that's sized using either `padding-bottom` or `aspect-ratio` and all the ratios are identical.

In my example, each child element has a ratio of 0.8 (200px x 250px) and the grid itself has gutters of 40px.

In one row, however, I want a column to span two columns, which is not a problem, but when I do that it seems I'm missing something when it comes to calculating the child element's new aspect ratio to *insure that all child element heights* match. I've tried this using both grid and flexbox, and using the `padding-bottom` method or `aspect-ratio` and the results are the same.

I simply add two widths of the base image size I'm using (200px) and then I add one gutter;

```
200px + 200px + 40px = 440px
```

Despite that, the only window width that the double column's child is the same height as the others is at 1015px.

What am I missing?

Code below and @ https://codepen.io/cfxd/pen/bGvvVMr (with some JS help to see dimensions and ratios and you can switch the first element's class between `padding` and `ar` to switch between using `padding-bottom` and `aspect-ratio`)

```js
function displayDimensions() {
  const els = [
    document.querySelector('.grid .item:nth-child(5) .ratio'),
    document.querySelector('.grid .item:nth-child(6) .ratio'),
    document.querySelector('.flex .item:nth-child(5) .ratio'),
    document.querySelector('.flex .item:nth-child(6) .ratio'),
  ];
  els.forEach((el) => {
    el.innerHTML = `${el.getBoundingClientRect().width}x${el.getBoundingClientRect().height}<br>(ratio: ${el.getBoundingClientRect().width / el.getBoundingClientRect().height})`;
  });
  document.querySelector('.window').textContent = `window: ${window.innerWidth}x${window.innerHeight}`;
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', displayDimensions);
window.addEventListener('resize', displayDimensions);
```

```css
:root {
  --gutter: 40;
  --gutter-px: calc(var(--gutter) * 1px);
  --image-width: 200;
  --image-height: 250;
}
*, :after, :before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: var(--gutter-px);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.window {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 8px 12px;
}
.grid, .flex, .item, .ratio {
  width: 100%;
}
.flex, .grid {
  gap: var(--gutter-px);
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  --grid-gutter: calc(var(--gutter-px) * 3 / 4);
}
.grid .ratio {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.grid .item:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column: span 2 / span 2;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: var(--gutter-px);
  width: 100%;
  --col-width: 25%;
  --col-gutter-px: calc(var(--gutter-px) * 3 / 4);
}
.flex .ratio {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}
.flex .item {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: calc(var(--col-width) - var(--col-gutter-px));
  flex: 0 0 calc(var(--col-width) - var(--col-gutter-px));
}
.flex .item:nth-child(5) {
  --col-width: 50%;
  --col-gutter-px: calc(var(--gutter-px) / 2);
}

.padding .ratio {
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: calc(var(--image-height) / var(--image-width) * 100%);
}
.padding .grid .item:nth-child(5) .ratio {
  --image-width: 440;
}
.padding .flex .item:nth-child(5) .ratio {
  --image-width: 440;
}

.ar .ratio {
  aspect-ratio: 0.8;
}
.ar .grid .item:nth-child(5) .ratio {
  aspect-ratio: 1.76;
}
.ar .flex .item:nth-child(5) .ratio {
  aspect-ratio: 1.76;
}
```

```html
<div class="padding">
  <div class="window"></div>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="ratio"></div>
      <p>Text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="ratio"></div>
      <p>Text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="ratio"></div>
      <p>Text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="ratio"></div>
      <p>Text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="ratio"></div>
      <p>Text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="ratio"></div>
      <p>Text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="ratio"></div>
      <p>Text here</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="ratio"></div>
      <p>Text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="ratio"></div>
      <p>Text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="ratio"></div>
      <p>Text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="ratio"></div>
      <p>Text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="ratio"></div>
      <p>Text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="ratio"></div>
      <p>Text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="ratio"></div>
      <p>Text here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/cfxd/pen/bGvvVMr

Comment: I think the issue is that you're doubling the width and adding the gap as though all of the values are constant, but in reality, the widths are dynamic (1fr) and the gap is static (40px), so you lose the relationship to the other tiles. If you make the gap 0px, then it works, since you're no longer accounting for static gap values. I'm not sure the solution with this approach, but there may be a better strategy out there to achieve the same effect, perhaps with setting the grid row heights.

Comment: @Rice_Crisp thanks for the comment, it ultimately helped me work out the solution (posted below!)

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a bit of a hack to get this working. Initially, I decided to set a fixed height for each box but using a relative unit like `vw`. Unfortunately, that required a lot of responsive adjustments.

What ultimately worked was creating essentially a duplicate of the grid within a double wide grid item, with two columns, and all box ratios—even the two boxes inside the double wide item—are set to the desired aspect ratio. This creates a seamless, uniform looking grid, except within the double wide element I added another box (3 boxes total) which I then position `absolute` and stretch to equal the double width and single height.

Unfortunately there are two boxes in use that aren't exactly semantic, but it does the trick.

Here's the working grid with a double wide child element that maintains equal heights with its neighbors: https://codepen.io/cfxd/pen/NWYmRpY

**Edit:** turns out it can be done with only one additional, non-semantic box: https://codepen.io/cfxd/pen/gOeyLmB

**Edit 2:** adding a more realistic codepen: https://codepen.io/cfxd/pen/QWmPdLN